# How does the spell Mind Blank interact with shapeshifters and other forms of false identity?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, shapeshifting

The description of the [*Mind Blank*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mind-blank) spell states:

> Until the spell ends, one willing creature you touch is immune to psychic damage, any effect that would sense its emotions or read its thoughts, divination spells, and the charmed condition. The spell even foils *wish* spells and spells or effects of similar power used to affect the target's mind or to gain information about the target.

How does the spell *Mind Blank* interact with shapeshifters and other forms of false identity?

- For example, can a guard give a description of a changeling's persona via *sending*, since it is not their natural form?
- Wish has a range of self but is still foiled for determining information about the target. Does that also apply to information about one of their fake identities?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't understand at all what is being asked here.

Comment: I think the crux of the question is on a very specific reading of *Mind Blank*, in which while a subject is under the effect of *Mind Blank*, no spell of any kind can be used to convey any information about the subject, even if the subject is not actually the target of the spell - i.e. *sending* someone a description of the subject is considered to be a spell which causes someone to gain information about the target and is therefore prevented.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I have tried to simplify the question as best as I can tell. Please tell me if it is still not clear.

Comment: @kent Carcer cleated things up for me, I think, but it doesn’t seem reflected in the question.

Comment: Please don't edit questions that already have answers in a way that makes those answers invalid - ask another question; they're free.

Answer (score 4):

### *Mind Blank* only affects magic

It does not protect the creature from being seen or perceived by things that aren't listed. If a guard encounters a changeling (or anything else) under the effect of *Mind Blank* they could describe what the saw and heard and smelled and, if things got that intimate, touched and tasted. Any "any effect that would sense its emotions or read its thoughts, divination spells, and the charmed condition" would fail but normal senses aren't affected. So, the guard can tell another guard what they saw, or take out an ad in the paper or send a *Message* because none of those actions is prohibited by *Mind Blank*.

Further, the *creature* is immune, the guard can use things that sense emotions, divination spells and charm things - just not on the *Mind Blank* target.

Comment: "For example, can a guard give a description of a changeling's persona via sending since it is not their natural form?"
The spell does absolutely nothing to prevent third parties from exchanging information of any kind by any means. It only stops magic from affecting the creature, not _other_ creatures. You might be better off asking that as a separate question though.

Comment: @StopBeingEvil not anymore.

Comment: @DaleM Okay I see this is an example of https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11186/i-asked-a-bad-question-how-should-i-fix-that 

I don't want to edit the question to match your answer because that is not a question I would ask. And you don't want to let me focus the question to deal with the close votes at the risk of invalidating your answer. Is there are way to resolve this situation? The question refers to identity and information, not perception.

Comment: @kent yes. Leave this question alone and ask the question you want to ask as a different question

Comment: I will contemplate asking a separate question. In the mean time the question is being rollbacked to when it had two examples up, I hope this does not invalidate your answer but your rollback went too far imo.